# Boolean passed in props causing error message when used

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to use a boolean to differentiate behaviour between SearchSections which are outer sections and inner sections using the boolean outerSection. The code works perfectly until I add the "outerSection &&" to the OverlayTrigger in SearchSection.js. When I do that, I get the error message: "React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child."

I know that outerSection is a boolean because when I console.log() the value in SearchSection, I do get true/false, not undefined. What am I doing wrong here? The code is using other props like props.display without any problems.

SearchResult.js:

```
return(
<div className="container" data-cy="all-search-results">
    {/* what happens if we get a result from the the db call*/}
    {!isFetching &&
      !error &&
      data !== null &&
      data !== "empty" &&
      results.filter(filterFunc).map((result, word_index) => (
        <SearchSection
          key={word_index}
          display={result}
          index={word_index}
          type={_type}
          outerSection={true}

        ></SearchSection>
      ))}
  </div>
</div>
 );
```

Relevant portions of SearchSection.js:

```
const SearchSection = (props) => {
let outerSection = props.outerSection;

//the information variable is set elsewhere in the code
if (information !== "") {
        infoBtn = (
            <Button
                style={{marginTop: "0.1em", marginLeft: "0.7em"}}
                variant="btn bg-white rounded shadow-none"
                onMouseDown={(e)=> {e.preventDefault()}}
                    onMouseLeave={() => setShowTooltip(false)}
                    onMouseEnter={() => setShowTooltip(true)}
                    onClick={() => handleInfoLinkClick()}
                data-cy="infoButton">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} size="xl" color="navy"/>
            </Button>
        )
    
}
<div className="definition__icon definition-title__tooltip-icon">
                <OverlayTrigger
                    placement="bottom"
                    overlay={renderInformationToolTip}
                    show={persistTooltip||showTooltip}
                >
                    {outerSection && infoBtn}
                </OverlayTrigger>
            </div>
```